# Difference between + and << in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Below are two identical classes with the difference of the operators `+` and `<<`. These can be found in the inject method. In the `+` case the tests pass and in the `<<` some of them fail. Why?

```
class Integer
  ROMAN_NUMERALS = {
    0 => '',
    1 => 'I',  2 => 'II', 3 => 'III', 4 => 'IV', 5 => 'V', 6 => 'VI', 7 => 'VII', 8 => 'VIII', 9 => 'IX',
    10 => 'X',  20 => 'XX', 30 => 'XXX', 40 => 'XL', 50 => 'L', 60 => 'LX', 70 => 'LXX', 80 => 'LXXX', 90 => 'XC',
    100 => 'C',  200 => 'CC', 300 => 'CCC', 400 => 'CD', 500 => 'D', 600 => 'DC', 700 => 'DCC', 800 => 'DCCC', 900 => 'CM',
    1000 => 'M', 2000 => 'MM', 3000 => 'MMM'
  }

  def to_roman
    to_s.reverse.chars.each_with_index.inject("") do |roman_numeral, (character, index)|
      ROMAN_NUMERALS[character.to_i * 10 ** index] << roman_numeral
    end
  end
end
```

I get different results to when I run

```
class Integer
  ROMAN_NUMERALS = {
    0 => '',
    1 => 'I',  2 => 'II', 3 => 'III', 4 => 'IV', 5 => 'V', 6 => 'VI', 7 => 'VII', 8 => 'VIII', 9 => 'IX',
    10 => 'X',  20 => 'XX', 30 => 'XXX', 40 => 'XL', 50 => 'L', 60 => 'LX', 70 => 'LXX', 80 => 'LXXX', 90 => 'XC',
    100 => 'C',  200 => 'CC', 300 => 'CCC', 400 => 'CD', 500 => 'D', 600 => 'DC', 700 => 'DCC', 800 => 'DCCC', 900 => 'CM',
    1000 => 'M', 2000 => 'MM', 3000 => 'MMM'
  }

  def to_roman
    to_s.reverse.chars.each_with_index.inject("") do |roman_numeral, (character, index)|
      ROMAN_NUMERALS[character.to_i * 10 ** index] + roman_numeral
    end
  end
end
```

The tests I am using are below

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'roman'

class RomanTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_1
    assert_equal 'I', 1.to_roman
  end

  def test_2
    assert_equal 'II', 2.to_roman
  end

  def test_3
    assert_equal 'III', 3.to_roman
  end

  def test_4
    assert_equal 'IV', 4.to_roman
  end

  def test_5
    assert_equal 'V', 5.to_roman
  end

  def test_6
    assert_equal 'VI', 6.to_roman
  end

  def test_9
    assert_equal 'IX', 9.to_roman
  end

  def test_27
    assert_equal 'XXVII', 27.to_roman
  end

  def test_48
    assert_equal 'XLVIII', 48.to_roman
  end

  def test_59
    assert_equal 'LIX', 59.to_roman
  end

  def test_93
    assert_equal 'XCIII', 93.to_roman
  end

  def test_141
    assert_equal 'CXLI', 141.to_roman
  end

  def test_163
    assert_equal 'CLXIII', 163.to_roman
  end

  def test_402
    assert_equal 'CDII', 402.to_roman
  end

  def test_575
    assert_equal 'DLXXV', 575.to_roman
  end

  def test_911
    assert_equal 'CMXI', 911.to_roman
  end

  def test_1024
    assert_equal 'MXXIV', 1024.to_roman
  end

  def test_3000
    assert_equal 'MMM', 3000.to_roman
  end
end
```

See how the specs fail in one case but not in the other. I thought these are meant to work in the same way.

Comment: Now you wrote a completely different question.

Comment: Side note: this should be probably written with a `map.with_index` + `join` at then end.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? The differences are clearly explained there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is a problem...

```
ROMAN_NUMERALS[character.to_i * 10 ** index] << roman_numeral
```

It will return a string which is the value of the correct `ROMAN_NUMERALS` key plus `roman_numeral`, which is what you want, BUT it is also changing the value in the `ROMAN_NUMERALS` hash!  The `shovel` operator `<<` changes the string on the left of the operator (it's what we call a mutating operator).

So if you test for 1001 the unit `1` will return "I" (that's fine) then the zero will return an empty string BUT will change the value for zero into "I"... the second zero will return "I" (incorrect) and will change the value for zero into "II".  The `1` in the thousands position will return "M" but then change the hash value into "MII".

Answer (score 2):

When the line `ROMAN_NUMERALS[character.to_i * 10 ** index] << roman_numeral` is being executed you are replacing the value corresponding to the key `character.to_i * 10 ** index` with its value plus `roman_numeral`.

Comment: Hi, good edit on my post, but I re-thought about the results and had to revamp the second half, so your edit sort of went into the wind...

Comment: It's ok, @SteveTurczyn. :)

Answer (score 2):

Now that your question has been answered, I would like to suggest an alternative method and also a different way to perform your tests. This requires Ruby v1.9+, so we can depend on the order of the hash keys.

**Code**

First, reverse the order of the hash elements.

```
RNR = Hash[ROMAN_NUMERALS.to_a.reverse]
  #=> {3000=>"MMM", 2000=>"MM", 1000=>"M",..., 2=>"II", 1=>"I", 0=>""}
```

Then:

```
class Integer
  def to_roman
    num = self
    roman = ""
    while num > 0
      i,r = RNR.find { |i,r| i <= num }
      roman << r
      num -= i
    end
    roman
  end
end
```

**Test objectives**

We need to test a substantial number of integer values and make sure that we are testing each integer against the correct roman numeral equivalent.  Both of these objectives can be met by creating a method that converts roman numerals to integers:

```
RNRI = RNR.invert
  #=> {"MMM"=>3000, "MM"=>2000, "M"=>1000,..., "II"=>2, "I"=>1, ""=>0} 

class String
  def roman_to_integer
    num = 0
    roman = self
    while roman.size > 0
      r, i = RNRI.find { |r,m| roman =~ /^#{r}/ }
      num += i
      roman = roman[r.size..-1]
    end
    num
  end  
end
```

**Examples**

Now let's invoke both `Integer#to_roman` and `String#roman_to_integer` for various integer values:

```
def check_one(i)
  roman = i.to_roman
  puts "#{i}.to_roman = #{roman}, #{roman}.roman_to_integer = " +
    #{roman.roman_to_integer}"
end

check_one(402)  # 'CDII'
  # 402.to_roman = CDII, CDII.roman_to_integer = 402
check_one(575)  # 'DLXXV'
  # 575.to_roman = DLXXV, DLXXV.roman_to_integer = 575
check_one(911)  # 'CMXI'
  # 911.to_roman = CMXI, CMXI.roman_to_integer = 911
check_one(1024) # 'MXXIV'
  # 1024.to_roman = MXXIV, MXXIV.roman_to_integer = 1024
check_one(3000) # 'MMM'
  # 3000.to_roman = MMM, MMM.roman_to_integer = 3000
```

**Tests**

So now in your testing you can use:

```
def test_all(n)
  (1..n).each { |i| test_one(i) }
end

def test_one(i)
  roman = i.to_roman
  assert_equal(i, roman.roman_to_integer, "#{i}.to_roman=#{roman}, " +
    "#{roman}.roman_to_integer = #{roman.roman_to_integer}")
end
```

Comment: Thanks. However I would imagine this is a bit slower? Since it is cycling from the number being converted down to zero vs the number of digits. Interesting approach though.

Comment: I suggest you benchmark and report back in the form of an answer.  If you've not used [Benchmark](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) before, it's very easy. See, for example, my answer [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

Comment: Looks like yours is faster.